# SIR model exact solution

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

I try to understand how the exact solution for infectious from [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/48173364_A_note_on_Exact_solution_of_SIR_and_SIS_epidemic_models) works, in order to prove that we cannot have "two waves of infectious" with fixed parameters.

The exact solution for the infected is
$ i(t)=\dfrac{\lambda}{\beta+\lambda \left(  \dfrac{\lambda-i_0\beta}{\lambda i_0 e^{\dfrac{\beta (s_0 + i_0 -1)}{\mu}}} )\right) \cdot e^{-\lambda t + \dfrac{\beta (s_0+i_0-1)}{\mu}} }$

I'm confused because it seems to me that $\beta,\lambda,\mu,i_0,s_0$ are fixed so the only term not fixed is $e^{-\lambda t +\dfrac{\beta (s_0+i_0-1)}{\mu}}$ according to $t$. But I feel that am wrong because the graph of inctious is as a wave, not as an exponential function.

My question is about where am I wrong and do you have any clue in order to prove that simple fixed SIR model infection has only one wave ?

edit: typo in exponential, missed "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you mean is that, intuitively, the share of infected people is not monotone (increasing/decreasing), unlike the setup of SIx models, which predicts, roughly speaking, the average of the rate of decay, without accounting for minor variations. They can predict, given the hyperparameters, if the virus will consume the whole population, or die out eventually, but not the size of deviations from the trajectory. This is because hyperparameters are fixed. For something more involved you have to look into dynamic models, where the rates of recovery/infection are the functions of time, i.e. $\mu, \lambda=\mu(t),  \lambda(t)$.